# How to Cache JSON Response to generate HTML for Navigation and Branding of a website?

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc-4, navigation, branding

What I am trying to do is that I have a set of three websites hosted on three different clients(A,B,C). One of the website(That is B) carries information about the headers and footers of the site A. I want to get information from the SITE B in a JSON response of HTML to display the Navigation on the SITE A and SITE C.

My understating is that to get the response is JSON and save that information in the cache file to generate HTML.

**Is my understanding correct? How can I achieve this? Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: You want to cache HTML result or JSON result from your controller ?

Comment: @Guillaume The controller will return JSOn result and I want to render cached data as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to cache JSON result from your controller's action, you can use [`OutputCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute :

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10)] //Duration is in seconds
public ActionResult GetMyJsonData() {
  var myData = new Data();
  return Json(data);
}
```

You can apply the same attribute on your action that returns the HTML.

Comment: The point is how can we access cached data in third party application. I have saved the site A navigation HTML in cache, the application has a single sign-on implemented with the third party website. how can the third party website can get the cached HTML and display the cached HTML on their site on runtime.

Comment: You did not mention this like that. You third party site has to perform a web call to `GetMyJsonData` on the first site. Another solution is to create a shared cache strategy using Redis for example.